# My whole Wi-Fi network crashed and nothing works. Is the issue the cable modem or my wireless router?

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, modem

The cable modem was knocked off the desk it was on and suddenly nothing works! I own my Motorola DOCSIS 3.0 modem, it worked fine with Comcast. I had it connected to my TP-Link  router (running DD-WRT). I also had a Cat 5 cable backhaul to another router that I configured as an access point.

Now, ut suddenly it all stopped working. I can connect a single computer to the modem output (WAN) with a Cat 5 cable and that works. But the TP-Link router doesn’t seem to recognize that WAN cable any more.

When I installed DD-WRT I set the IP address of the TP-Link to be 192.168.1.1.

Shouldn’t I be able to connect my MacBook to one of the 4 ports with a cable and point my browser at 192.168.1.1 and log into the TP-Link router running DD-WRT? Because even that’s not working.

Comment: hm, its worth confirming the second router *is* set up as an AP, and checking if you can connect to the router on its own. Also, rather than assuming the router IP is .1.1, double confirm via ifconfig what the gateway IP is

Comment: Sounds like the TP-Link router _might_ have been damaged. At least the ethernet port. Can you connect the TP-Link router directly to your MacBook and see if that connects?

Comment: There is no possible way we can determine if the issue is the cable or the device itself based off the information you provided

Comment: Sounds like the dd-wrt router is stuffed.

Comment: When you switched from the single computer directly connected to the modem to having the TP-Link router connected to the modem, did you fully power cycle the modem? DOCSIS modems latch onto the first MAC address they talk to at boot and refuse to talk to anything else. So if you didn't power off you modem while making the switch, then your modem is ignoring your router.

Comment: @Spiff.  that is a great point. i have seen that in action.